# How to navigate to a file URL using Vue vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

Is there a way using `vue-router` to navigate to a URL path with a file extension?

I have many file types that need to be accessed this way (ie.- ".txt", ".json", ".pdf", ".xlsx"...).

Example (entering url into search bar):
`mysite.com/documents/file.txt` <-- Wanted, but does not work
`mysite.com/documents/file` <-- Not wanted, but Works

Where `file.txt` could then be used as a param to download the file.
Currently using a file extension in the path results in a 404 error.

I've tried doing the following to the route config, both trying to navigate to `mysite.com/documents/file.txt`:

```
{
  path: "documents/:name",
  name: "documents-file",
  component: () => import("@/pages/MainPages/DocumentPage.vue")
},
```

This gives 404 when navigated to with file extension.☝️

```
{
  path: "documents/:name.:extension",  // <-- regex doesn't work either
  name: "documents-file",
  component: () => import("@/pages/MainPages/DocumentPage.vue")
},
```

Also gives 404 when navigated to. ☝️

[image]

I also can't use server settings, since I'm running the app on DigitalOcean's serverless App platform.

Vue: "^3.2.31"
vue-router: "^4.0.13"

Comment: Request header have value Content-Type: text/txt you can get extension from there.

Comment: @Mises Can you explain more?

Comment: @Mises I know how HTTP protocols work. I don't see where your solutions is. Are you suggesting I just use the url without the file extension? Because that's not what I'm trying to do. I know how to get the file type if I have the file name. But there are several file types that I'm storing that I would like to have URL paths for. And someone elses code is looking for the path with the file extension added to the URL.

Comment: If you have same filenames and multiple file extensions, i would try: `path: "documents/:name.:extension"`.

Comment: @Mises Unfortunately that just gives a 404 like I had explained. I've added an image showing that as well.

Comment: try prepending a '/' at the start of the path, I mean this

    /documents/:name.:extension

 I had a similar issue before no idea why this fixed it.

Comment: @NoName Thanks for the suggestion, still gives me a 404 page instead of using my component logic...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to **navigate** to files directly with `vue-router`. There is a difference in your Vue app between clicking on a file link and entering a file url directly into the browser.

I know this isn't really an answer to your original question, but ***I think*** that the `vue-router` will not **navigate** to static files directly by design. **So you should change how you navigate to those static files.**

The best solution I found is to use simples `<a>` tags instead of the `<router-link>` component. [According to mousetail](/questions/71873351/how-to-bypass-router-for-certain-urls-with-vue-router#comment127009157_71873351), `<router-links>` work differently than `<a>` tags:

> Be careful with your links. Vue router has special links that don't make a network request.
> Use them only when you actually don't want a network request.
> If you want to link to a external site or a page not served via vue link to it directly

We can also see this if we look at the source code of [`<router-link>`](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/RouterLink.ts):

```js
export function useLink(props: UseLinkOptions) {
  const router = inject(routerKey)!
  const currentRoute = inject(routeLocationKey)!

  const route = computed(() => router.resolve(unref(props.to)))

  /* (redacted for readability) */

  function navigate(
    e: MouseEvent = {} as MouseEvent
  ): Promise<void | NavigationFailure> {
    if (guardEvent(e)) {
      return router[unref(props.replace) ? 'replace' : 'push'](
        unref(props.to)
        // avoid uncaught errors are they are logged anyway
      ).catch(noop)
    }
    return Promise.resolve()
  }

  /* (redacted for readability) */
  
  return {
    route,
    href: computed(() => route.value.href),
    isActive,
    isExactActive,
    navigate,
  }
}
```

If you want to link directly to files, I recommend you wrap the `<router-link>` component in another component. Example with a Single File Component and a `render` function:

```html
<!-- 'SimpleLink.vue' -->
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    target: { type: String },
    routed: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  },
  render() {
    // Make sure to bind all the other props of <router-link> if you want to
    // use this example. I excluded them to provide a minimal working example.
    if (this.routed)
      return h("router-link", { props: { to: this.target } }, this.$slots.default());
    return h("a", { attrs: { href: this.target } }, this.$slots.default());
  },
};
</script>
```

which can later be used after importing with:

```html
<simple-link target="../some/file.pdf" :routed="false">Some file.pdf</simple-link>
```

Comment: There is not a way to navigate to files directly from vue-router. In order to be able to navigate to the files, it would have to be server side rendered. Since vue and vue-router are in a front-end environment and pre-rendered, the public directory (which is where the file would be), can not be edited or added to. So the file has to exist already.